# How to use rotary encoder like a button for Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, encoder

First sorry for my bad english and I hope u understand what I mean

I want make something with arduino Uno that makes a pwm signal with 50% duty cycle and variable frequency between 10 hz and 2Khz on pin 13

I want to set the frequency with an rotary encoder in such way that when I rotate the encoder one step to left, it likes up button pressed and when I rotate it one step to right it likes down button pressed

I don't want there is a counter, when I rotate to left counter+1 and when I rotate to right counter-1

I don't want the location of encoder between -infinite to 0 to +infinite

I want it do like two buttons

I hope u understand what I want

Comment: Rotary encoder is project #2 on the small Atmel parts, right after blinking an LED.  Simply create a two pin change interrupts and when A occurs before B, that's clockwise movement.  When B fires before A, that's counter-clockwise movement. Update volatile variable.  Fifteen lines of code and no ridiculously bloated library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Encoder library by Paul Stoffregen available in Library Manager, you can reset the count with `encoder.write(0)`.

```
  int direction = encoder.read();
  if (abs(direction) >= ENCODER_PULSES_PER_STEP) {
    if (direction > 0) {
      // do something for step up
    } else {
      // do something for step down
    }
    encoder.write(0);
  }
```

Comment: @CherryCHTR, yes, in Library Manager in IDE